# Query selecting parameters issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am stuck in the following issue :-

```
var userid = req.params.userid;
var category = req.params.category; 
// category can be basicinfo, address, contactinfo, etc

var selection = {
        category: 1
    };

User.find({ _id: userid}, selection){.......}
```

The `category` which is passed as parameter doesn't reflect in the query selection. so, when i run the above code it runs like this: -

```
`User.find({ _id: userid}, category: 1){.......}`
```

What i expect is :-

```
`User.find({ _id: userid}, basicinfo: 1){.......}`
```

What is solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var category = req.params.category;
var selection = {};
selection[category] = 1;
User.find({_id:userid}, selection){...}
```